# Using ng-bind with a variable predicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible to use a predicate value for an ng-bind statement.

For example, I want to bind a td element that will change the property it displays dynamically.

```
<td ng-bind="user.month"></td
```

What if I wanted to change that element binding dynamically to

```
<td ng-bind="user.week"></td>
```

What would be the best way to achieve this.  I'd have a `select` element that determines which predicate should be used for binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `[]` object notation where you pass the variable bound to your select in the `[]`

Assuming you have:

```
<select ng-model="models.selectVal">
```

And some data in scope like:

```
 $scope. data = {
    item1: 'Text in item 1',
    item2: 'Item 2 text'
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
 <div ng-bind="data[models.selectVal]"></div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iH1VKrZnbanXXkOvOTIJ?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly this!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that just like that.
There are two options that solve your problem.
First (and the one that I recommend), don't change the binding. Make an extra field in your scope and change that field.
Second option, you can change the ng-binding and then recompile the angular template, see [Angular compile documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

I hope this was helpfull. 
Good luck!!